# If $(f \ast g)(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n}f(d)g(\frac{n}{d})$, prove that $\ast$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, convolution

If $(f \ast g)(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n}f(d)g(\frac{n}{d})$, prove that $\ast$ is commutative. I believe this is convolution.

My attempt at the proof:

$(f \ast g)(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n}f(d)g(\frac{n}{d})$

$= \sum\limits_{d|n} f(\frac{n}{k})g(k)$ ($d|n \Rightarrow \exists k$ s.t. $n = kd$)

$= \sum\limits_{d|n}g(k)f(\frac{n}{k})$

$= (g \ast f)(n)$

Note that I found this question in an abstract algebra book.

Comment: What is the $(d\mid n)$ to the right of the summation symbol?

Comment: You need a little more.  You need to show that the map $d \mapsto n/d$ from divisors to divisors is bijective.

Comment: @Andres: You are right there are many errors in the formulas here.

Comment: I made a few tweaks and obtained the following above now.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:
$$(f\ast g)(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}f(i)g(j)\mathbf 1_{ij=n}\qquad\&\qquad\mathbf 1_{ij=n}=\mathbf 1_{ji=n}.
$$
Notation: for every property $P$, $\mathbf 1_P=1$ if $P$ is true and $\mathbf 1_P=0$ if $P$ is false.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you mean by $\boldsymbol{1}_{ij=n}$. I understand it, the OP may have problems.

Comment: @egreg Done, good idea, thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I follow what your saying because the title of this topic is literally what it said when I found it, so I feel like I should solve it using the way they wrote it. Maybe what you have is the same, but if that is the case I do not think I am following.

Comment: The RHS of the first identity in my post is (obviously) invariant by the transformation $(f,g)\mapsto(g,f)$ because of the symmetry explained in the second identity. Do you see why this solves your problem, exactly "the way they wrote it"?

Comment: So $(f \ast g)(n) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty}f(i)g(j)1_{ij = n} = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty}g(j)f(i)1_{ji = n}$? And I still dont see how this relates to what the problem actually says.

Comment: The RHS in your last comment is $(g\ast f)(n)$, hence you proved that $f\ast g=g\ast f$. Still unrelated to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Write it as $$\sum_{ab=n}f(a)g(b)$$